# How to convert a specific sheet of an Excel file into XML in Mule?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-cluster

In Mule, I want to convert an excel file to xml file, but my Excel file has 2 sheets and I just wanted the 2nd sheet of Excel file to be converted into XML. Is it possible ?

How to convert a specific sheet of Excel file into XML using Mule ?

(eg : I need to convert just the second sheet)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to implement a custom converter using apache POI (this is, if you are using Mule CE). Otherwise, DataMapper should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

- In the Latest version of mule datamapper is deprecated.
- Use dataweave component or java code to perform the transformation.